# Please could you help me finding global warming video with ice melting in glass time messurment scene?

Tags: climate-change, water, ice

Few months ago I watched a video posted on reddit about climate change and in it there was scene showing glass of water with ice cubes.

They were measuring how long it takes for ice to melt and then after ice is melted how rapidly water warms. My best guest was Guy McPherson or Bill Nye video, not sure about Cowspiricy, but I have now seen I do not know how many and I could not find that scene.

I am looking video (scene) that shows how glass full of water stay for 40min+ at the same 1C temperature while ice is there, but as soon as ice melts, temperature of water increases to 25C (room temperature) just in 5 minutes. There was a glass of water with timer and thermometer, displaying melting ice and rise of temperature.

Basically it makes a point that without ice water warms more rapid.

Is there anyone there that has maybe seen the video please can you send me the link or tell me where it was?

Comment: You do not really need the video for that, it's basic physics: the melting of a certain amount of ice takes a certain amount of energy (334 J/g). Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice): *When ice melts, it absorbs as much energy as it would take to heat an equivalent mass of water by 80 °C. During the melting process, the temperature remains constant at 0 °C.* [Sample calculation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n5iL3Gg_mg)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the specific video you are looking for, but here is one:

The video [Latent heat of fusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wEJMtCcTfo) shows the effect that you mean in a real world situation where the water is not mixed well.
The video [Determination of Melting Point of Ice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk4vhD2X4Ew) shows it under more controlled conditions.

The video [Heat in changes of state](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STURzRg7LDQ) explains it with a graph.

The video [Energy required to melt ice and warm the water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n5iL3Gg_mg) gives you an actual calculation example and shows the energy involved in melting ice vs. heating water.

Comment: Thank you Jan, I needed specific video and instead I have got lecture from physics. :)
Reason why I need video is more with me showing than displaying formulas. 
Also it was part of some climate change video so I would like to know which one.